# External monitors often too bright with MacBooks?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have two MacBook Pro laptops, a 13" 2012 and a 15" 2019. I want to get an external monitor.

I tried using the Dell 2410 and the BenQ GW2480 external monitors.  Both monitors were too bright with either of my MacBooks in my bedroom even when the monitors were set to minimum brightness.

Do MacBooks make external monitors brighter than Windows laptops, or does a monitor's brightness have nothing to do with the type of computer?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is even an Apple centric question as the brightness range of the monitor has nothing to do with the MacBook; you'd have the same problem with a Dell, HP, Asus, etc.  I know of no monitor spec sheet that tells you the minimum (or range of) lumens of a monitor - they usually list the max to tell you how bright it can get.  So, the only way I would know is to go into a store and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *range* of brightness of a monitor is dependent on what the manufacturer designed and is irrelevant to the computer (Macs and PCs) attached to them.

#### Lumens or Units of Visible Light

The amount of [*lumens*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumen_(unit)) a display puts out (how dim and bright it goes) is totally dependent on how the manufacturer designed and built it.  For simplicity, think of it like the "volume" control for audio, but instead of sound, it handles light.  The fact that it doesn't go to "zero" (or low enough for your particular needs) is due to the design - there may be a technical reason like the LEDs that the manufacturer used may only work properly within a certain voltage range.

#### Computer Control

Your MacBook (or any laptop) can send control signals to dim or brighten the monitor but when it reaches it's lowest point, that's as far as it goes.  Your computer can't make it go any lower.

#### Finding Your Monitor

Now, to find a monitor that suits your needs, it's unfortunately going to be "trial and error."  Go into a store and test them out.  If online, you'll likely have to test out buy and return a few (could get expensive because it's technically not faulty so return shipping would be on you).  [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) here on StackExchange may be helpful, but you'll need to be much more specific as to how dim you want this monitor to be because hardware manufacturers rarely (if ever) tell you how low their monitors can go - it's usually max brightness they promote.

Comment: RE:  Hardware Recommendations site, be aware that they have (IMO) a very rigid standard for asking questions there.  [Review their guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and be sure you hit all their points even if irrelevant (like price) and be *very, very* clear on how dim you want it to be.  Find an analogy, to compare it to, research a chart/comparison of lumens to candlepower. anything to put a value to your brightness level.  What's acceptable to you is different for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a digital dimmer in addition to the built-in display dimmer, see for example https://github.com/sidneys/desktop-dimmer/releases. I am not sure though whether it can dim more than what the monitor is able to.

You can also solve the issue by buying a mac screen protector, there are lots of different types and any anti-glare / matte / filtering film should help out, though I cannot say which films will take away the most light.

I am using a film on my laptop screen, I would not be able to work without it, I would have raised eyebrows from the constant mirroring. My screen protector film takes away some brightness so that I could even use it in complete darkness, that would not be possible without.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  In my experience digital dimming apps (e.g. Shady) reduce the contrast of the screen.  I could try using a screen protector.

Comment: @CollegeStudent Consider perhaps a film with blue light reduction, at least that would be what I would go for if I bought something new. It might really bring some relief to the eyes, at least there cannot be just a conspiracy theory behind, and it obviously must reduce the light a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Monitor brightness generally does not depend on what device you connect to it.

You can use apps like DisplayBuddy that can use the DDC protocol to control the brightness of your monitors (same as using the buttons on your monitor)